# How Do I Move a Git Repo from Beanstalk to Github?

Tags: git, github

I have my code repo in [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/). How do I move the code from Beanstalk to [Github](https://github.com/)?

Answer (score 16):

The recommended way to do this is to:

```
git clone --bare url/for/beanstalk/repo.git .
git push --mirror git@github.com:user/repo.git
```

Also see here: https://help.github.com/articles/importing-an-external-git-repo

Comment: Fantastic answer, also works the other way (Github to Beanstalk).

Comment: Will that copy the commit history as well ? (and all of the branches ?)

Answer (score 5):

#### From the [GitHub Documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-an-external-git-repo)

```bash
# In this example, we use an external account named extuser and
# a GitHub account named ghuser to transfer repo.git

# Make a bare clone of the external repo to a local directory
$ git clone --bare https://githost.org/extuser/repo.git

# Push mirror to new GitHub repo
$ cd repo.git
$ git push --mirror https://github.com/ghuser/repo.git

# Remove temporary local repo
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf repo.git
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already where using Git at beanstalk you can simply create a empty repository on GitHub and then add it as a remote on your local repo.

(assuming your repo is in ~/project)

```
cd ~/project
git remote add github <github-ssh-url-here>
git push github --all --tags
```

Comment: You can `push --all` too -- and `push --tags` for tags

Comment: I did as per the advice but i am not getting the branches

Answer (score 0):

The other answers given here did not work for me, but with the incredible help of Dan from [Fork](https://git-fork.com) (even showing me that I didn't need his product at all!), I got the following steps which made transferring my 9 repos out of Beanstalk and into githuhb, an absolute breeze.  Hope they help someone else as well.

> 1. Open terminal
> 2. Create a temp directory in your user directory: `mkdir ~/moverepos`
> 3. Open this directory: `cd moverepos`
> 4. Clone your old Beanstalk repo: `git clone --bare <url/repositoryName.git>`
> 5. Open the directory with repo: `cd repositoryName.git`
> 6. Open Github, create a new EMPTY repo of the same name and copy it’s url.
> 7. Push data to new destination (GitHub in our case): `git push --mirror <newUrl/repositoryName.git>`
> 8. If this is the first time you have done this process, you should be prompted for your Beanstalk username and password.  Enter them now
>      and watch the repo push to github.
> 9. If you are done, you may delete your temp directory in Finder and stop here.
> 10. If you want to move more repos, navigate to the root of “moverepos”: `cd ..`
> 11. Goto 4.