# Move source code from existing repo to new with keeping history

Tags: git, github

We have existing repo and I have to move source code to new repository with keeping history.

Comment: this question not lied in this category please ask it in User experience.

Comment: @ArpitKumarKulshrestha the question is about a software tool used primarily by programmers, it fits pretty well here according to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @ArpitKumarKulshrestha what are you talking about? This is a (poorly written) legitimate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move external repo to Github](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538362/move-external-repo-to-github)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a repo on Github, then using the command line

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git remote set-url origin <github URL>
git pull origin master
git push -u origin master
```

Basically you're changing the default `origin` remote URL to point to the Github one.

Comment: well.... after running "push" command, I've got - did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: You probably mistyped the name. What's your github repo and what did you type in exactly?

Comment: well, now I typed new git url correctly, but now I've got another erro:

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github..git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
....

Comment: try pulling the repo first. Updated my answer.

Comment: yep, there were conflicts in .gitignore but finally it's done, thanks a lot