# Set a new repo from an existing local repo (previous have remote repo but then deleted)

Tags: git, github

I have a course that sets up the GitHub repo for every students' repo and each student can see their own repo. After the class, all the repos were being deleted. Now I have my local repo and would like to set a new repo under my account for it and remain the commit history.

Since the time is long, restore the remote repo is not possible. When I use Github Desktop I can get access to the history of the repo, but cannot fetch origin since the original repo was deleted.

Is there any other ways I can try that I can remain the history of the repo?

Comment: You can create new repo in your account then add it as new remote in your local repo then push code to new remote using git push new-remote-name

Comment: Luckily, I've already find the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463339/move-source-code-from-existing-repo-to-new-with-keeping-history. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move source code from existing repo to new with keeping history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463339/move-source-code-from-existing-repo-to-new-with-keeping-history)